# Converting an HVAC Connection

Tags: circuit-breaker

Have since moved my HVAC with ”old” connection now idle; dbl 40 amp breaker remains, with #8 wire, I have established a sub panel with 2 split 20 amp breakers to feed 2 outlets, should I replace the said dbl 40 amp breaker at main center with a dbl 20 amp breaker to reduce the feed, and will the existing #8 wire be OK????

---

Technically, yes they are outdoors-even though covered by patio roof; and yes,boxes, outlets are all exterior-GFCI-sealed systems-with box covers, and sealed conduit connections.

---

Yes, there is a ”new” sub panel, exterior rated, Sq. D, 50 amp, 2 breaker, 4 circuit.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's a little hard to understand what you mean; would you add a diagram or picture? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: I take it this new subpanel is feeding outdoor receptacles, no?

Comment: No, I do not know of anyone who could answer my question.

Comment: Please click the [edit] button below your post to include all the info you've provided in the "Answer" boxes below. While you were, technically, "answering" questions posed to you in the comments, the "Answer" box is for providing an answer to the question you've asked. As Daniel suggested, taking the [tour] will help you get a better feel for how things work at this Q&A site, since it's different from your typical internet forum.

Comment: How many wires are in the existing cable going to the new subpanel?